# How to get the x and y position of the last sprite in an arraylist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-android

I am using cocos2d-android and eclipse, language is java.

I have an arraylist of sprites (maximum of 50 sprites) that I generate at the start of my game. I delete the sprites when their positions are off-screen. I want to add new ones (to the arraylist) when a sprite is deleted but the y position of the new sprite is above the last sprite in the arraylist. I can generate new sprites but I can't get the y position to be above the last sprite in the arraylist.

Thank you in advance for the suggestions and answers.

Comment: please post your code.So that we can help you

Comment: Do you want your sprites move from down to top?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) instead of ArrayList. Look at its **addLast**, **getLast** and **removeLast** methods.
Hope I understood your problem ;)